# How can I calculate the adress of a dynamic symbol in a binary at runtime?

Tags: c, linker, binary, memory-address

I am facing a difficulty with one of my program. I need to be able to tell when a CALL is executed, to what function symbol the address of the call is linked to.

I understand that with my own function I need to parse the .symtab section of my elf binary, but symbol linked to a shared library does not have any address.

I also parsed the .dyndsym .rela.dyn .rela.plt and .dynstr sections. With that much of information, I now know which function goes with which library.

I understand that the function address given in the shared object will not be the same as the function address in the binary. Also all my program (written in C) are compiled with the option "-fno-stack-protector".

My question is : Is there a way to calculate the address of a dynamic symbol before executing the binary ?

Comment: I think I didnt understand your problem but, allocating the function in a specific address through the linker could solve your problem? You dont need to know where it is because you are choosing where it is. The linker doesnt care if it is a shared library or not

Comment: what I am trying to do is to know in advance the position of a function in the binary if this function comes from a dynamic library. For exemple if you parse the symtab section, you may find "main" and it's offset position. With this information I know for exemple, if I have a CALL instruction during a trace, that the address is the main function. I want to do the same with all functions that comes from the dynamic libraries. As an example : if I add dlsym() in my code, I need to compile with -ldl, where will be dlsym() in my program when I execute it ?